# Update multiple columns from subquery

Tags: mysql, sql

This type of thing has been asked a few times before, but is not quite what I am looking for. I need to `SET` two rows equal to different parts of a subquery.

I am currently using:

```
UPDATE records
SET leads=(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM leads_table WHERE leads_table.blah=records.blah),
earnings=(SELECT SUM(amount) FROM leads_table WHERE leads_table.blah=records.blah)
```

The WHERE statements were obviously simplified...but basically its the same subquery but I don't think I should be running it twice?

I want to do something like...

```
UPDATE records
SET (leads,earnings)=(SELECT COUNT(*),SUM(amount) FROM leads_table WHERE leads_table.blah=records.blah)
```

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You can simply join the table in a subquery that do some calculations,

```
UPDATE  records a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  blah, 
                    COUNT(*) totalCount,
                    SUM(amount) totalSum
            FROM    leads_table
            GROUP   BY blah
        ) b ON  b.blah = a.blah
SET     a.leads = b.totalCount,
        a.earnings = b.totalSum
```

Comment: Nice indeed, elegant and fast.

Comment: Is it fast? Would it not calc count/sum for every blah even if you are only selecting one?

Comment: Works for me. Thanks

Comment: needs a comma after the first set

Comment: I think it works well but beware if all rows in leads_table referring to a specific row of records are removed, I don't think it will update the field in records back to zero properly, so would need to zero all first.