# MySql combining update with an inner join and limit

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to update a row in table `amga` with just one row from table `amgb` joined by their `itemTempId`.

My problem is that, there may be upto 6 rows in table `amgb` for that `itemTempId`and I need to use only one from it for the update.

I'm familiar with doing updates with joins, but when I added a Limit (so as to get just one row) I get the error message `Incorrect usage of update and limit`. I read that this is not possible, but would there be another way to do this?

**amga**

```
"id"    "itemId"    "itemTempId"    "itemImageName" "itemName"                  "itemCountry"   "userId"
"1"     "US1"       "T001"          \N              "Samsung Galaxy Note 5"     "US"            "1"
"2"     "CA2"       "T002"          \N              "Samsung Galaxy Note 6"     "CA"            "2"
"3"     "UK3"       "T003"          \N              "Samsung Galaxy Note 7"     "UK"            "3"
```

**amgb**

```
"id"    "itemId"    "itemTempId"    "itemImageName"     "userId"
"1"     "US1"       "T001"          "front.jpg"         "1"
"2"     "US1"       "T001"          "side-left.jpg"     "1"
"3"     "US1"       "T001"          "side-right.jpg"    "1"
"4"     "US1"       "T001"          "back.jpg"          "1"
"5"     "CA2"       "T002"          "front.jpg"         "2"
"6"     "CA2"       "T002"          "side-left.jpg"     "2"
"7"     "CA2"       "T002"          "side-right.jpg"    "2"
"8"     "CA2"       "T002"          "back.jpg"          "2"
"9"     "UK3"       "T003"          "front.jpg"         "3"
```

**Sql I used**

```
update amga a inner join amgb b on a.itemTempId = b.itemTempId 
set a.itemImageName = b.itemImageName where a.itemTempId = 'T001' limit 1;
```

**Expected results: Table amga after update**

```
 "id"   "itemId"    "itemTempId"    "itemImageName" "itemName"                  "itemCountry"   "userId"
    "1"     "US1"       "T001"      front.jpg       "Samsung Galaxy Note 5"     "US"            "1"
    "2"     "CA2"       "T002"      \N              "Samsung Galaxy Note 6"     "CA"            "2"
    "3"     "UK3"       "T003"      \N              "Samsung Galaxy Note 7"     "UK"            "3"
```

Note: `itemTempId` is updated with `front.jpg`, which is the first row for `itemTempId = T001` in `amgb`

Any help appreciated.

**Update**
I noticed it works if I remove the limit, and that it updates too. But is it the right way to do it? What does MySql do with the other rows in the select?

```
update amga a inner join amgb b on a.itemTempId = b.itemTempId 
set a.itemImageName = b.itemImageName where a.itemTempId = 'T001';
```

Comment: How are you defining "the first row" when joining? I suppose it is not a random row, is it the row with the lowest id? (As there is no guaranteed order of rows in a table.)

Comment: The first / highest one. In this case it'll be `1`

Comment: And for `T002` (if `T002` is used in the update) it'll be `5`

Comment: Okay, so the one with the lowest `id` :-)

Comment: In MS SQL I would solve this with a ranking function, so you first do a ranking on `amgb` and then join every row with the corresponding row ranked 1. Seems something along those lines could be done in MySQL too: [Mysql rank function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3333665/mysql-rank-function).

Comment: See my update to the question.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use a subquery:

```
UPDATE amga a
SET a.itemImageName =
  (SELECT b.itemImageName
   FROM amgb b
   WHERE b.itemTempId = 'T001'
   ORDER BY b.id LIMIT 1)
WHERE a.itemTempId = 'T001'
```

Comment: In your sql, is it possible to update two columns with data from the select Eg: `SET.itemImageName, SET itemImagePath = (select b.itemImageName, b.itemImagePath etc.) `

Comment: Afaik, unfortunately not. But you can try the following update statement with a join. I'm not adding it to the answer since I'm not sure. You may format and try it: UPDATE amga a
INNER JOIN
  (SELECT b.itemImageName,
          b.itemImagePath
   FROM amgb b
   WHERE b.itemTempId = 'T001'
   ORDER BY b.id LIMIT 1) c ON c.itemTempId = a.itemTempId
SET a.itemImageName = c.itemImageName,
    a.itemImagePath = b.itemImagePath
WHERE a.itemTempId = 'T001'; I checked out this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16473402/update-multiple-columns-from-subquery

Comment: I'll try. Im using your first answer. Thanks for that.